# ios 10 webview xcode swift geolocation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, geolocation

I have a webview `html5` page that `does not work in ios 10` i does not load the users location, the app working in ios9 and below. I don't get my location from http://html5demos.com/geo in safari on ios10, i have tried 3 different phones, am i missing or did something change for ios 10? see code below

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        let url = NSURL (string: "http://html5demos.com/geo");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
        webview.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hey Corey, did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10 html5 geolocation available for ssl connection (https) only. For example you can try

`let url = NSURL (string: "https://maps.google.com")`

and it should work for you.